# HP Smart Array P410i Logical Volume failed, how to rebuild it without lossing data

Tags: hp-smart-array

I have a failed logical volume on an HP Smart Array P401i with vmWare installed.  Is there any way to rebuild the logical volume without losing precious data?

[logical volume failed on vmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goiFJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will rebuild the disk for you. dig up a replacement disk (same specs as the failed disk or better) and swap it out . You may notice some degradation while it rebuilds. look at disks 3-7, at least one of them will have a warning light on.

Comment: Yes, I have already replaced the defective disk, all of them are now blinking green. how long will it take to rebuild?

Comment: It varies depending on how big the disk is, how fast the machine is, etc... I would wait 24 hours and the check it, should be done or close to it by then. There should be a hp application installed that you can use to watch it's progress..

Comment: Thank you very much! Keeping my finger crossed.